# AS: if statement evaluating incorrectly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a very simple piece of logic as follows:

```
var divert:Number = 0;
for (var connection in _connections) {
    trace("target: " + _connections[connection].target + " || i: " + (i + 1));
    if(int(_connections[connection].target) != (i + 1)) {
        trace("bad connection");
        divert++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when `i + 1` and `int(_connections[connection].target)` are equal the if statement is returning `true` as can be seen in the output of my `trace()` statements below:

```
target: 0 || i: 1
bad connection
target: 1 || i: 1
bad connection
```

Can anyone see what could be causing this to happen?

EDIT: The function this is contained in as per request:

```
public function loadListener(i:Number, onProgress:Function, onComplete:Function):Void
    {
        trace("load listening to: "+i);
        trace("next in queue: " + _queues["lower"][0] + " | " + _queues["upper"][0]);
        _functions[i] = {onProgress:onProgress, onComplete:onComplete};
        if (_queues["lower"][0] != i + 1 || _queues["upper"][0] != i + 1) {
            var divert:Number = 0;
            for (var connection in _connections) {
                trace("target: "+_connections[connection].target+" || i: "+(i+1));
                if(int(_connections[connection].target) != (i + 1)) {
                    trace("bad connection");
                    divert++;
                }
            }
            if (divert == _connections.length) {
                _diversion = i + 1;
                trace("divert: "+divert+" || connections: "+_connections.length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is "i" in your code, could yu show a more elaborate example?

Comment: @DennisJaamann `i` is just a variable cast as a number which is passed to the function as a paramater. The rest of the code is long and verbose and pretty much irrelevant to this issue. I will update the code with the function this is wrapped in if it helps.

Comment: @sch `typeof(_connections[connection].target)` returns `object`, however it is initially a number and I typecast it into a number in the if statement `int(_connections[connection].target)` its value is `0`

Comment: is it AS2? did you try `Number(_connections[connection].target)`? question tagged both as2 and as3 looks really strange btw

Comment: @www0z0k yes it is AS2 I tagged both because there was nothing very version specific here and AS3 guys could help also (there are more people subscribed to AS3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why use a `for(var)` loop when you can use

```
var divert:Number = 0;
for each(var connection in _connections) {
    trace("target: " + connection.target + " || i: " + (i + 1));
    if(int(connection.target) != (i + 1)) {
        trace("bad connection");
        divert++;
    }
}
```

To debug further, replace

```
trace("target: " + connection.target + " || i: " + (i + 1));
```

with

```
trace("target: " + int(connection.target) + " || i: " + (i + 1));
```

If this traces zero, you know where the issue is.

You could try doing

```
if(connection.target.toString() != (i + 1).toString()) {
```

Comment: Thanks tracing `int(_connections[connection].target)` does output a `0`, do you know why it would convert it to a `0`? I found out that using `parseInt()` works though and so did your string method. Also I am actually working in AS2 where we can't use `for each in` loops but tagged it as AS3 because I saw the issue as version agnostic. Thanks.